# Monitor Email For Alerts

Tags: email, monitoring

I need a online web service or software which can monitor multiple email inboxes for the subject title of something similar to: "Alert - Level 1"

Then email my personal email or send an SMS to myself so i can check it out.

Before i write my own, i just thought there may be one out there

There will be 20+ email inboxes to monitor at one time

Comment: Most mail servers support server-side rules for things like that. Have you checked if yours does that already? Then you'd just have to setup the rules. At least forwarding to another mail address is usually possible; SMS services are rather rare in that category.

Comment: Yup, Gmail can certainly do that. I use it in that way for sending email, but not for SMS.

Comment: Is it your own mail server?

Comment: If you have a shell account where you receive your mails, you can set up procmail to do the filtering and email you. To send a SMS, you'll have to use an external service.

Answer (score -1):

I think Thunderbird's filters can do it. You'll have to make a new rule to forward the message if their subject contains "Alert". Take a look at this page: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-up-message-filters-in-thunderbird/
You can apply a filter on several inboxes.

Comment: The downside is that this only works when retrieving the mails. I guess that if the OP needs to catch alerts, he wants *automatic* monitoring at specified intervals, even if he does not retrieve any mails.

Comment: You can set Thunderbird to retrieve the mails every minute so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that your solution needs Thunderbird to be up and running 24/7.